# Using RTRIM in a CREATE TABLE Field in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, trim, create-table

Hi I'm trying to create a table

and i would like to minimize the trailing spaces of the fields i'm trying to create.

below is a sample code that 
if i wanted to trim the field "datefield1" what would be the proper way of doing it inside the create table script?

```
Create Table test
( field1 number(5),
  field2 number(5),
  datefield1 date,
  datefield2 date);
```

Comment: The `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` functions operate on strings, not dates

Comment: Trim it how?  Do you mean you want to store just the date, and not the time?

Answer (score 0):

Check [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1847).

"Date data is stored in **fixed-length fields** of seven bytes each, corresponding to century, year, month, day, hour, minute, and second."